# O que fazer com perguntas que tem votação negativa, mas a mesma tem sentido?

Tags: debate, voto-contra

O que fazer em caso de perguntas que atraem votos negativos por usuários que as interpretaram incorretamente, ou, não possuem conhecimento de caso para respondê-la e por isso negativam a pergunta achando que a solução é trivial, quando na verdade você já tentou ao máximo se expressar, inclusive via comentários e os mesmos continuaram sem entender "estudar" pelo menos o que você se dispôs a compartilhar com a comunidade, mas os mesmos não entenderam?

Por exemplo: eu fiz uma pergunta no fórum "Qual a melhor alternativa open-souce para representação em Flowchart com Javascipt?"

Um dos membros entende que `Flowchart` é algo do `DOS`, não sei de que época ele é, aí já negativou minha pergunta.
Outro achou que eu queria "reinventar a roda", mas esse eu sinalizei e foi removido o comentário "ofensivo/engraçadinho".

Minha dica é que os membros procurem soluções e entender a pergunta, ou pelo menos os termos técnicos que nela estão contidos para que consigam pelo menos não estar equivocados em suas votações.

Se tivesse feito isso perceberia que: `FlowChart` é um serviço que permite a criação de diagramas de fluxo sem a necessidade de instalar qualquer software ou plugin no computador(...).

A sua pergunta "saí" de foco por conta dessas votações, e você acaba sem respostas como é o meu caso, infelizmente.

Comment: Independente da questão dos votos (porque é difícil controlar como as pessoas votam), eu achei a pergunta confusa, e [comentei isso lá](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81087/qual-a-melhor-alternativa-open-souce-para-representa%c3%a7%c3%a3o-em-flowchart-com-javasci?noredirect=1#comment168188_81087) agora. *Flowchart* é um tipo de gráfico, um diagrama de fluxo. Não é um serviço. Entendi que você está buscando uma ferramenta, mas não saquei quais seriam os requisitos dela pra te atender.

Comment: @bfavaretto é exatamente isso que desejo (você quer é desenhar automaticamente (lendo os dados do banco)), mas eu procuro uma solução open-source.

Comment: A princípio não necessito de drag and drop, seria mais exibir mesmo o que "já foi desenhado", pois a entrada eu posso fazer por campos mesmo, sem necessidade de usar necessariamente a parte WYSIWYG  ( o que você vê é o que você obtém )

Comment: A pergunta faz sentido para você, para outras pessoas não faz. Se várias pessoas não entendem o que você quer e você é que está precisando da ajuda, você tem que se esforçar em melhorar. O que dá para fazer é mudar para que fique em condições de serem respondidas de acordo com os parâmetros do site. Se ninguém entende, ninguém vai responder, se alguém conseguir entender, vai responder mesmo que a pergunta esteja com negativos. [help]. E concordo com o bfavaretto.

Comment: Você pede uma coisa no título, no meio diz que quer outra coisa, no comentário muda o rumo. Pra mim a pergunta deveria ser fechada como muito ampla se considerar o título ou o que está escrito no corpo, se não for isto, aí ela deve ser fechada por não estar clara. E nem vou falar que é baseada em opiniões porque dá para abstrair essa parte. Vou aguardar você tentar salvá-la antes de votar. Quando tem muito comentário na pergunta é porque ela está ruim. Quando ninguém sabe do que se trata, a pergunta morre sozinha. Neste caso não morreu, ela apenas está incompreensível.

Comment: @bigown editei a pergunta e a explicação. Podes verificar agora.

Comment: Outra coisa, aí o cara vai, edita a pergunta do cara toda errada e sem nexo, com erros de ortografia e sintaxe na descrição, código sem conexão nem formatação, dá parte da solução pra ele, outro cara pega  a solução proposta por mim, otimiza, aí eu fico negativado e o cara positivo. Meio injusto http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/82172/armazenar-m%C3%BAltiplos-checkbox-com-php-mysql/

Comment: @MaiconHerverton Parece que você ainda não entende o funcionamento do site. O que aconteceu é que você fez uma edição, como não tem previlégio suficiente essa edição foi para a fila de análise. O que fiz foi clicar no botão "melhorar" o que significa que eu aprovei sua edição e ainda dei mais uma melhorada. Isso não significa que você ficou "negativado" muito menos eu "positivo" como você diz...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Li sua [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81087/227) agora e o respectivo histórico.

O problema aqui é realmente o que alguns colegas já indicaram em comentários, isto é, ela estava bastante confusa para outras pessoas lerem.

Alguns termos, tal como *flow chart*, são sobrecarregados e outros requisitos da biblioteca que você procura não estava claros. Uma dica é sempre colocar um link para uma definições que usar e exemplos do resultado esperado logo de início.

No estado atual já melhorou bastante, porém, ao contrário do que você sugeriu na pergunta aqui do meta, o que atrapalha uma pergunta é muito mais a sua falta de clareza do que o voto negativo.

O problema é que a maioria dos usuários lê a pergunta, não entende e parte para a próxima. A discussão que ocorreu em comentários mostra que alguns usuários vão além disso e pedem esclarecimentos ou tentam ajudar com o que puderam entender.

Reclamar de que os outros não entenderam o que você escreveu sem ninguém mais para apoiar sua afirmação é meio sem sentido. Você pode ter o problema extremamente claro em sua mente, mas para os outros não é assim.

Além disso, cada vez que você edita sua pergunta, possivelmente melhorando-a, ela vai para a página inicial do site novamente.

Por último, peço que não fique chateado com qualquer crítica que tenha recebido. Veja isso como uma oportunidade de melhorar um pouco sua comunicação também. **Todos** passamos por isso em algum momento, seja aqui ou no trabalho. Não pense que ninguém aqui tem algo especificamente contra você ou sua pergunta.